# How can I make ui-router controller to work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I've set up two simple URLs, with simple different templates and the same controller, but it doesn't work

HEAD:

```
<script src="jsLib/angular_v1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jsLib/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="routes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCTRL as ctrl">
{{ctrl.nameApp}}
<div ui-view></div>
```

app.js:

```
angular
    .module("app", ["ui.router"])
    .controller("MainCTRL", MainCTRL)
    .config(configA);


function MainCTRL($location){
    this.nameApp = "nameApp";
}
```

routes.js:

```
function configA($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state("/",{
           url: "/",
           templateUrl : "/testingBlock.htm",
           controller : "MainCTRL"
        })
        .state("login",{
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl : "/app/templates/login.htm",
            controller : "MainCTRL"
        });

}
```

login.htm:

```
<div>Header</div>

<div>Main</div>

<div>Footer</div>

{{name.nameApp}}
```

testingBlock.htm:

```
 <h2>Hello goHenry</h2>

{{MainCTRL.nameApp}}
```

It doesn't display MainCTRL.nameApp

Comment: Your console probably display an error, could you copy it ?

Comment: try updating angular version to `1.3.16`

Comment: The my one is 1.4 version

Comment: you are creating new instance of controller inside view and not using `controllerAs` so `MainCTRL` is undefined in expressions

Comment: @Donovant seems it helped ;) great, enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to show you where is the issue, but did not found any. But then I realized that the issue is inside of the state views.

There is [a working version of your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/7H5OCcCOsyOjcKs6qx18?p=preview).

All adjustments are really very small (not important). The index.html

```
<html ng-app="app" >

  <head>
    <title>my app</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="routes.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head> 

  <body ng-controller="MainCTRL as ctrl">
    {{ctrl.nameApp}}

    <br><a href="#/">#/</a> - default 
    <br><a href="#/login">login</a>

    <hr><div ui-view=""></div>

  </body> 
</html>
```

The big one is here **`"controllerAs"`**

```
$stateProvider
    .state("/",{
       url: "/", 
       templateUrl : "testingBlock.htm",
       controller : "MainCTRL",
       controllerAs:"MainCTRL",
    })
    .state("login",{
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl : "app/templates/login.htm",
        controller : "MainCTRL",
        controllerAs:"name",
    });
```

So, what is different? to support these statements:

- `{{name.nameApp}}` in the  "testingBlock.htm",
- `{{MainCTRL.nameApp}}` in the "app/templates/login.htm",

We need to use controllerAs and name as name or MainCTRL (compare your code and [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/7H5OCcCOsyOjcKs6qx18?p=preview))

NOTE: do not mix `ng-controller` and `UI-Router` *states* controllers. These should be different objects, because `UI-Router` can use other **resolve** then the angular native `ng-controller`. Later it could bring surprises...

Comment: but it's not printing the OP expression inside the view

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for help, finally we should have working plunker and the answer ;)

Comment: Yep, I've just realized 30sec ago that I needed to set "controller" and "controllerAs"

Comment: `controllerAs` is the whole answer really, the `not important` part of this answer is really incorrect...it is important

Comment: You can just set up "controllerAs", that's it.